# Discuss the convergence of the sequence who's nth term is given by...

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$a_n = \left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n$$

Please explain the process of how this is solve, I'm really confuse and struggling on how to figure out series and sequences. Since this is a sequence, is l'hopital or squeeze theorem involved?

Comment: Do you know the definition of constant e?

Comment: I think (1+(1/n))^n= e, but with 1/2n added I get confuse.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2n}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}e}$$

Comment: How did you get it to go to square root?

Comment: @Andrea: $x^n=x^{2n \cdot 1/2}=(x^{2n})^{1/2}=\sqrt{x^{2n}}$

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an other approach, if you're familiar with expansions:

$\ln(1+u) = u + o(u)$ when $u\rightarrow 0$

$\exp(u) = 1 + o(1)$ when $u\rightarrow 0$

$a_n = \exp(n\ln(1-\frac{1}{2n})) = \exp(n[-\frac{1}{2n} + o(\frac{1}{2n})]) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2} + o(1)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\exp(o(1)) $

=> $a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}(1 + o(1)) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} + o(1)  $

Hence $a_n \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$